# Environment variable not visible after `sudo su`

Tags: bash, sudo, environment-variables

I have an environment variable setup in user `user_a`'s `.profile`:

`export NODE_ENV=dev`

When I log in as the user and launch a bash shell, if the environment variable is correctly set. If I do `echo $NODE_ENV` I get `dev` printed out as expected.

If I log in as a different user `user_b` and then become `user_a` via the command `sudo su user_a`, the environment variable is not set.

How do I ensure that the environment variable `NODE_ENV` is set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you issue the command `su user` you will switch to the user without loading their entire profile. Only the `$HOME`, `$SHELL`, `$USER`, and `$LOGNAME` variables are loaded. In order to load the user's entire profile when switching to it you have to specify that you are logging in the the user by using the `--login` flag, which has a shortcut as a single dash (`-`) after su, so your command will look like `su - user`.

Comment: This is a better approach for what I'm trying to do. Would like to avoid mucking about with the system wide config `/etc/sudoers.d/envkeep` file if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to add `env_keep += "NODE_ENV"` to a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/`. I would recommend doing it as follows:

1. Run `sudo -i` to have a root shell in case something goes wrong (I messed this up one time and it was really annoying to fix).
2. In a separate shell, do `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/envkeep`
3. In that file, add `Defaults env_keep += "NODE_ENV"`
4. After saving, exit and try `sudo -i`. It should work and put you in a shell where `NODE_ENV` should have been preserved.